# Is it possible to remove the print dialog header/footer?

Tags: css, printing, media

I have an online application that the user needs to print. However, I don't want the default header/footer included in the print dialog:

[image]

Can I change that programmatically? I know there is an option, but I don't want to have to rely on the user unchecking that box.

[image]

Comment: No. YOu can't control how the browser prints this. At most you can make minor hints, and headers/footers is not one of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that as far as I know.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I further understand what you want. I agree with Moin. There is no programmatic way to do this (that I am aware of at least).